# Javascript + CSS animation not working, what could be causing it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a page progress loader, I would like to animate the width throughout progress however I am not having any luck. Please see below, any help would be most appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/nbx9dwzL/

**HTML**

```
<div id="page-progress-bar-top"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var pageProgressBarTop = document.getElementById("page-progress-bar-top")
pageProgressBarTop.classList.add("complete")
```

**CSS**

```
#page-progress-bar-top{
  position:absolute;
  height:4px;
  background:#12ADFD;
  z-index:100;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  -moz-transition: all 3s;
  -ms-transition: all 3s;
  -o-transition: all 3s;
  transition: all 3s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 0px rgba(179,179,179,0.82);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 0px rgba(179,179,179,0.82);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 0px rgba(179,179,179,0.82);
}
#page-progress-bar-top.complete{
  width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no *initial* `width`, and the *default* `width` for a `<div>` element is `100%` (it's a block element).

To see the transition, you're looking to apply a `width`, of say `1px` to start out with:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var pageProgressBarTop = document.getElementById("page-progress-bar-top")
  pageProgressBarTop.classList.add("complete")
});
```

```css
#page-progress-bar-top {
  width: 1px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 4px;
  background: #12ADFD;
  z-index: 100;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s;
  -moz-transition: all 3s;
  -ms-transition: all 3s;
  -o-transition: all 3s;
  transition: all 3s;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 0px rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.82);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 0px rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.82);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 7px 0px rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.82);
}

#page-progress-bar-top.complete {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-progress-bar-top"></div>
```

This can be seen working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/z1kuL0ab/).

Comment: I'm curious: why did you remove the SO snippet in favour of the JSFiddle? I clicked "run code snippet" a couple of times and, indeed, it was not working. Do you know why?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado; I'm curious about that too. The StackSnippet was indeed not working, and I didn't want to add additional code that wasn't directly tied to the resolution of OP's problem. I assume the StackSnippet problem lies in timing / sand-boxing, though adding a click event handler seems to resolve the issue for the StackSnippet. I've added this to the StackSnippet, and left the JSFiddle link there to show that you *shouldn't* need this.